# How to remove dummy account from android?

Tags: applications, accounts

When I go to factory reset my android device I found a "dummyaccount" on my device.

Does anyone know what this "dummyaccount" is and how can i permanently remove it from my device?

[image: Screenshot of dummyaccount]

Comment: Is there any other gmail account signed in the device?

Comment: In what state is the phone? Why do you want to factory reset it? What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: no, i have already removed google account before reset.

Comment: @esQmo_ my device became slow so i want to reset it.

Comment: You probably have been infected by some malwares. Have  you noticed weird/unusual behavior?

Comment: @esQmo_ no, haven't noticed any unusual behavior

Comment: So does this prevent you from doing what you need to do? You can still reset by key combo anyway. (power off. hold Volume up then briefly the power button. From the recovery, use Volume buttons to navigate )

Comment: @esQmo_ ok. Will try this and let you know

Comment: Removed dummy account by factory reset device. but, not found proper reason how it came into my device.

Comment: See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562432/hide-dummy-account-for-sync-adapter-from-settings). I would say that it was an account created by some app for their internal purposes. Also [see this](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer [is within this article](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html):

> **Add the Account Required by the Framework**
>
> The sync adapter framework requires each sync adapter to have an
>   account type. You declared the account type value in the section Add
>   the Authenticator Metadata File. Now you have to set up this account
>   type in the Android system. To set up the account type, add **a dummy
>   account** that uses the account type by calling addAccountExplicitly().

So the reason for this account was probably some app, that needed its local database to be synchronized with server using a sync adapter. This app has created account called `dummyaccount`. Some [tricks exist to hide this account from the account list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19562432/2224701) in Settings.